# How to enforce relational foreign key constraints in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a database with two tables, **PROCESS** `(PK Process_Id)` and **PROCESS_STAGE** `(PK Stage_Id, FK Process_Id)`.

At least I think I have set this up - in the foreign key relationships dialogue box I have

- Foreign key base table: **PROCESS_STAGE**,
- Foreign key columns: `Process_Id`,
- Primary/unique key base table: **PROCESS**,
- Primary/unique key column: `Process_Id`.

I have also set enforce for replication and enforce foreign key constraints to 'Yes'.

But I can still do the following things which break this relationship:

1. Delete items from **PROCESS** which have references from
   **PROCESS_STAGE**

What do I need to do to correct this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SQL to create the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE PROCESS_STAGE WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_PROCESSTAGE_PROCESS 
          FOREIGN KEY (Process_Id) REFERENCES PROCESS (Process_Id)
```

If this still fails, look at the tables schema/owner: you may have more than one table and you're using the wrong one. Example:

- dbo.PROCESS_STAGE
- deed02392.PROCESS_STAGE

Comment: I did try this @gbn, but I kept getting this error:

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PROCESSTAGE_PROCESS". The conflict occurred in database "A_A", table "dbo.PROCESS", column 'Process_Id'.

I only see tables called 'dbo.*' in the Tables tree of the database, so I suppose that means I should be using the right table?

Comment: @deed02392: if you only have dbo, then this is good. I suspect you have the same error when using the GUI. This will issue SQL similar to what I did above. Your FK fails because it is never created

Comment: I don't understand? It seems to be suggesting it can't create one because one already exists, but I don't see anywhere it does, and if it does then I shouldn't be able to delete records which break the relation?

Comment: It's failing because you have orphaned rows in PROCESS_STAGE.

Comment: Oops! I'd left that in there testing the constraints, obviously before I'd done it properly. SMS makes it confusing by letting you do these things without actually comitting to the db, hence revealing the error/reason why it won't do it... :P